# How to parse in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, saxparser

I use ruby 2.5.0 and gem 'sax-machine'

how to parse only image **url** with sax-machine or nokogiri

```
<media:thumbnail url="https://i2.ytimg.com/vi/E4txwB96eBk/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" height="360"/>
```

this doesn't work

```
 element :"media:thumbnail", as: :image, value: :url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with Nokogiri:

```
xml = %Q(<media:thumbnail url="https://i2.ytimg.com/vi/E4txwB96eBk/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" height="360"/>)
Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml).children.attribute('url').value
```